# Hierarquia de templates - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, template, documentação

Gostaria de saber de forma simples, de fácil entendimento, se alguém pode explicar sobre a hierarquia de templates do WP.
Já vi bastante a respeito, inclusive a imagem da documentação, mas por tenho dúvidas, a respeito de quanto usar o archive.php por exemplo e tals.

Se alguém  tiver uma explicação melhor sobre...

Answer (score 1):

Fala Peter.

Como você mesmo citou, a imagem da documentação já dá uma boa ajuda. Vou fazer um possível caminho e você responde com dúvidas se tiver. Então, basicamente é só criar os arquivos na pasta que o Wordpress faz a seleção.

### A imagem

[image: Imagem da documentação]

### Regra geral

Basicamente, o Wordpress irá seguir da esquerda para a direita, tentando achar o template adequado, de acordo com as alternativas.

Vamos supor que você tenha uma tag criada **"livros que li"**. Então, quando você digitar no endereço:

> sitecombr/livrosqueli

1. O Wordpress irá verificar se o que você está buscando é um autor, categoria, custom post, taxonomia, data ou tag. No nosso caso é uma **tag**.
2. Próximo passo é descobrir se você tem um arquivo no seu diretório raiz do tema chamado **"tag-livrosqueli.php"** ou **"tag-id_da_tag"**.
3. Caso não exista, tentar achar o arquivo **"tag.php"**.
4. Caso não encontre, o Wordpress irá tentar usar o arquivo **"archive.php"**, se tiver paginação, irá usar o **"paged.php"**.
5. Se tudo falhar, o Wordpress usa o padrão **"index.php"**.

### Uso dos templates básicos

- **archive.php**

  Usado para exibir grupos de post. Exemplo: Últimos posts do blog.
- **single.php**

  Usado para exibir o conteúdo de um post. Exemplo: Quando o visitante clica em um post dentro de uma lista de posts.
- **page.php**

  Usado para exibir páginas estáticas. Exemplo: Exibir páginas institucionais como "Quem Somos", "Sobre", "Contato"...
- **home.php**

  Usado para exibir os posts da home. Caso você tenha definido uma página estática como página inicial, o template usado será o **front-page.php**.
- **comments-popup.php**

  Usado para exibir os comentários de um post, quando abertos via popup (Acho que nunca usei este template, rs).
- **404.php**

  Usado para exibir um conteúdo específico quando um post não é encontrado.
- **search.php**

  Usado para exibir os resultados de uma busca no site.

Absss!

Comment: Opa, blzão Leonel?
Então, entendi sim sua explicação, era mais ou menos o que eu imaginava.
Mas minha dúvida é mais no archive.php por enquanto, tipo assim: Aqui na empresa um amigo desenvolveu um site e em um determinado lugar ele usou archive.php, e quando eu perguntei, disse que foi pq o archive.php é para um conjunto de itens, lista.

De qualquer forma, é uma confusão na minha cabeça, quando é melhor usar isso ou aquilo, o pq e tals...

Comment: Fala Peter. Eu editei a resposta veja se te ajudou. :D

Comment: Muitíssimo obrigado Leonel.
Minha última dúvida é a seguinte, vamos supor, que tenha que ter uma página que fale sobre o cliente, por exemplo e ela vai conter itens.

No caso eu vou fazer tipo archive-biografia.php, e nesse arquivo eu vou fazer o loop ou seja lá o que for neh?! 
E ae, como vou fazer pra esse archive ser chamado no menu biografia?

Pq achei que no menu, eu só conseguiria chamar se fosse página mesmo e tal...

Obs: Não sei se estou sabendo explicar o que tenho na cabeça...

Basicamente, como deixar claro que em determinado lugar terá que aparecer o archive-biografia...

Comment: Entendi que o WP percorre um caminho até chegar em determinado arquivo, ou no index como último, se não tiver o que teria de ser.

Mas o lance é só como fazer tal archive.php aparecer em determinado lugar...

Comment: Fala @PeterRoberto.

Primeiramente, que tipo de informação é "Biografia"? É uma categoria de posts? Uma tag? Um tipo customizado de post?

Identificando isso, você vai no diagrama da imagem e busca, por exemplo:

Se for uma "categoria", você irá usar o template: "category-biografia.php".

Se for uma tag: "tag-biografia.php".

Para aparecer no menu:

1. Vá em "Aparencia > Menus".
2. Marque todas as caixas no menu retrátil "Opções de tela" (Canto superior direito).
3. Então vc pode selecionar os itens do menus da esquerda e adicionar para seu menu.